# Prevent angularjs animation from running on element that is initially hidden when loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-animation

http://codepen.io/cflynn07/pen/hbgxf
^ Example

I have an angularjs animation, and I don't want it to run on page load for an element that is supposed to be hidden.

Right now, the element is shown, then the slide up animation occurs and hides the element.

Answer (score 3):

Is this something you're looking for?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JaHKL

Basically you need set `style="display: none;"` to declare the initial state.

Otherwise the initial state will be `display:inline` and when AngularJS reads `data-ng-show="false"`, it will trigger your `hide` animation in order to match your setting.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Instead of adding a link, please, can you add the relevant code?